# Making a view in a listview invisible android

Tags: android, listview, view

I have a `ListView` that's using a custom adapter. I want to dynamically add/remove items from the `ListView`. I've tried everything inside the `getView()` method in my view adapter. I've tried doing `setVisiblity(View.GONE)` on the view I'm returning. And it in fact doesn't draw the view, but it still allocates space for the view and it's just a blank black space.

Is this even possible to set items in `ListView` invisible?

Comment: Could you show how you set the item to GONE?

Comment: It should not allocate the space in the ListView if you set the returning view to GONE.

Comment: I agree that it should not allocate space, but it does...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove items from the `ListView` I would change the values that the associated `ListAdapter` returns rather than trying to manipulate the views.

Comment: Yes, instead of messing with the visibility, just remove them entirely.

Comment: I ended up creating 2 arrayLists and just shuttling my items back and forth (one complete list, and one displayed list)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call setVisiblity(View.GONE) on the returned view and all the views inside it. If you are reusing the convert view passed in you need to remember to call setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE) on all the views you want visible.

If you have a lot of invisible views you may need to set the divider height to 0 and add your own divider to the returned views. Otherwise the 'invisible' views will each have a visible divider and produce a noticeable gray line between visible views.